# ReactJS - render conditionally whitespace

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, html-entities

I'm trying to build a button-component which is able to have icons set before and after the element's children.

Therefore, the props are like this:

```
export interface IButtonProps {
    children?: React.ReactNode;
    leftIcon?: FontAwesomeIcon;
    rightIcon?: FontAwesomeIcon;
}
```

whereas `FontAwesomeIcon` is an enum holding the available icons.

In the button's `render`-function I do check if there is an icon set. If so, there should be the icon and a whitespace between the children and the icon.

```
render(): JSX.Element {
    let { children, leftIcon, rightIcon } = this.props;

    return (
        <button>
            {leftIcon && <FontAwesome icon={leftIcon} />}
            {leftIcon && " "}
            {children}
            {rightIcon && " "}
            {rightIcon && <FontAwesome icon={rightIcon} />}
        </button>
    );
}
```

Though this solution is working I wonder if there is an easier way than having to check twice for an icon to be set. Also I would like to have the ability to use `&nbsp;` instead of .
Is there any way to escape the whitespace so I can write something like `{leftIcon && <FontAwesome icon={leftIcon} />&nbsp;}`?

I tried `{leftIcon && <FontAwesome icon={leftIcon} />{"&nsbp;"}}` or `{leftIcon && <FontAwesome icon={leftIcon} />{&nsbp;}}` which leads to

> TS1005: '}' expected.

Comment: why don't you add style for this

Comment: @JigarShah would you mind adding an example on how you would use styles exactly?

Comment: Sure, I will try. Can you please create snack demo

Answer (score 0):

This article suggests that `&nbsp;` should work for intentional whitespace http://andrewhfarmer.com/how-whitespace-works-in-jsx/

Seeing as you should be able to insert `&nbsp;` inline with other HTML I would have thought you don't need to wrap it up in brackets or a string. Imagine it just like writing `<br />` and you should be able to glue it to the end of the `<FontAwesome />` component.

```
render(): JSX.Element {
  let { children, leftIcon, rightIcon } = this.props;

  return (
    <button>
        {leftIcon && <FontAwesome icon={leftIcon} />&nbsp;}
        {children}
        {rightIcon && &nbsp;<FontAwesome icon={rightIcon} />}
    </button>
  );
}
```

Disclaimer, this is untested

As an alternative, this github issue https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/1643 suggests you can add `{' '}` for intentional whitespace, so I'd have thought this would work too:

```
render(): JSX.Element {
  let { children, leftIcon, rightIcon } = this.props;

  return (
    <button>
        {leftIcon && <FontAwesome icon={leftIcon} />{' '}}
        {children}
        {rightIcon && {' '}<FontAwesome icon={rightIcon} />}
    </button>
  );
}
```

Disclaimer, also untested

Comment: First one gives me two errors. `TS2362: The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number' or an enum` and `TS2304: Cannot find name 'nbsp'.` The second one `TS1005: '}' expected.`.
So this is maybe more related to `TypeScript` then?

Comment: interesting, perhaps without the `{}` but with the `""` (I'm only guessing I'm afraid unable to test atm)